# Regular expression for getting first and last name ignoring middle names

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm searching a regular expression that could give me the first and last name in a string that is a complete name.

I searched but I didn't find one that fit my needs. For instance:

- Abc Def Ghi Jkl ---> Abc Jkl
- Aéc Def Gài Mkl ---> Aéc Mkl
- Aéc-Def Gài Mkl ---> Aéc-Def Mkl
- Aéc Def Gài-Mkl ---> Aéc Gài-Mkl
- Afd             ---> Afd

How can I build a regex to return me what is on the right side when the string is what is on the left?

Comment: Why use a regular expression when you can split the string and get the first and last index.

Comment: @jeff I could do that but I would like to understand better how regex works and with some pratical examples it is easier ;)

Comment: "*it is easier*" - no, no it isn't.

Comment: This might be a better use of split, but I've seen split get abused more because people use it as a crutch to avoid regular expressions.

Comment: [`yourstring.match(/^\S+|\S+$/gm).join(' ')`](https://regex101.com/r/jX5cK6/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wouldn't suggest regular expressions for this, the following, using `String.prototype.split()`, `Array.prototype.shift()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()`, seems much easier:

```
function firstAndLast(el) {
  // getting the text of the element:
  var haystack = el.textContent,
    // splitting that text on white-space sequences,
    // forming an array:
    names = haystack.split(/\s+/),
    // getting the first element of that array:
    first = names.shift(),
    // initialising the 'last' variable to an empty string:
    last = '';
  // if the names array has a length greater than 1
  // (there is more than one name):
  if (names.length > 1) {
    // last is assigned the last element of the array of names:
    last = names.pop();
  }

  // return an array containing the first and last names:
  return [first, last];
}

// getting all the <li> elements in the document:
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
  // creating an empty <span> element:
  span = document.createElement('span'),
  // an unitialised variable for use within the loop:
  clone;

// iterating over each of the <li> elements, using
// Array.prototype.forEach(), and Function.prototype.call():
Array.prototype.forEach.call(listItems, function(li) {
  // cloning the created <span>:
  clone = span.cloneNode();
  // setting the clone's text to the joined-together
  // strings from the Array returned by the function:
  clone.textContent = firstAndLast(li).join(' ');
  // appending that cloned created-<span> to the
  // current <li> element over which we're iterating:
  li.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```js
function firstAndLast(el) {
  var haystack = el.textContent,
    names = haystack.split(/\s+/),
    first = names.shift(),
    last = '';
  if (names.length > 1) {
    last = names.pop();
  }

  return [first, last];
}

var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
  span = document.createElement('span'),
  clone;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(listItems, function(li) {
  clone = span.cloneNode();
  clone.textContent = firstAndLast(li).join(' ');
  li.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```css
li span::before {
  content: ' found: ';
  color: #999;
}
li span {
  color: #f90;
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Abc Def Ghi Jkl</li>
  <li>Aéc Def Gài Mkl</li>
  <li>Aéc-Def Gài Mkl</li>
  <li>Aéc Def Gài-Mkl</li>
  <li>Afd</li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5w8cu6cd/).

It is possible to use regular expressions, just needlessly more complex:

```
function firstAndLast(el) {
  var haystack = el.textContent,
    // matching a case-insensitive sequence of characters at the
    // start of the string (^), that are in the range a-z,
    // unicode accented characters, an apostrophe or
    // a hyphen (escaped with a back-slash because the '-'
    // character has a special meaning within regular
    // expressions, indicating a range, as above) followed
    // by a word-boundary (\b):
    first = haystack.match(/^[a-z\u00C0-\u017F'\-]+\b/i),

    // as above but the word-boundary precedes the string of
    // of characters, and it matches a sequence at the end
    // of the string ($):
    last = haystack.match(/\b[a-z\u00C0-\u017F'\-]+$/i);

  // if first exists (no matching regular expression would
  // would return null) and it has a length:
  if (first && first.length) {
    // we assign the first element of the array returned by
    // String.prototype.match() to the 'first' variable:
    first = first[0];
  }
  if (last && last.length) {
    // as above:
    last = last[0];
  }

  // if the first and last variables are exactly equal,
  // we return only the first; otherwise we return both
  // first and last, in both cases within an array:
  return first === last ? [first] : [first, last];
}
```

```js
function firstAndLast(el) {
  var haystack = el.textContent,
    first = haystack.match(/^[a-z\u00C0-\u017F'\-]+\b/i),
    last = haystack.match(/\b[a-z\u00C0-\u017F'\-]+$/i);
  if (first && first.length) {
    first = first[0];
  }
  if (last && last.length) {
    last = last[0];
  }
  return first === last ? [first] : [first, last];
}

var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
  span = document.createElement('span'),
  clone;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(listItems, function(li) {
  clone = span.cloneNode();
  clone.textContent = firstAndLast(li).join(' ');
  li.appendChild(clone);
});
```

```css
li span::before {
  content: ' found: ';
  color: #999;
}
li span {
  color: #f90;
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Abc Def Ghi Jkl</li>
  <li>Aéc Def Gài Mkl</li>
  <li>Aéc-Def Gài Mkl</li>
  <li>Aéc Def Gài-Mkl</li>
  <li>Afd</li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5w8cu6cd/1/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS pseudo-elements, `::before` and `::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
  - [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call/).
  - [Guide to JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 2):

To your specific case where you have different chars, you must change the regex a little to suit your need, here is one that achieves what you need:

```
^([\w-éà]+)[^\w-éà].*?[^\w-éà]([\w-éà]+)$|^([\w-éà]+)$
```

Tested on regex101.com:

[image]

Explanation:

We must break the regex into two parts to make it easier to understand:

```
^([\w-éà]+)[^\w-éà].*?[^\w-éà]([\w-éà]+)$
```

This is the general case where you have at least two names.

The block [\w-éà] represents your character set.

You then use the start anchor (^) to tell the engine that you are looking for a match at the start of the line, then you get a group containing your characters set, until you find something that is not in your character set([^\w-éà]). you then use lazy quantifiers .*?  to match the first occurrence of the next pattern which is to match a word to the end anchor($).

The second part is just the one word case (^([\w-éà]+)$)

In this example group 1 will have first name when there is at least two names

group 2 will have last name when there is at least two names

and group 3 will have the name when there is only one name

Answer (score 0):

I would use `^` to match the beginning of the input, then parentheses `()` , the special `\w` character, and the `+` character to capture the first name. Then optional whitespace/characters, followed by more parentheses to capture the last name right before the end of the input, which is matched by the special `$` character. Here's an example:

```
var huge = 'Abc Def Ghi Jkl';
var small = 'Afd';

var regex = /^(\w+).*?(\w*)$/;
var results = regex.exec(huge);

console.log(results[1]); // 'Abc'
console.log(results[2]); // 'Jkl'

var results = regex.exec(small);

console.log(results[1]); // 'Afd'
```

There are many ways to do what you want, so I recommend reading [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

if you're passing only one full name for the regular expression use this one to get the first and last name 
`/^[^ \n]+|[^ \n]+$/g` , and if you're passing the list of all full names separated by a line between each full name use this `/^[^ \n]+|[^ \n]+$/gm` just by adding m at the end of the regex use this link for testing [regex to get first and last name from a full name](https://regex101.com/r/wY5jG5/2)

Answer (score 0):

Remember a well structured *Regex* should cover as many exceptions as possible not only the current existing examples - plus it should be designed in a way to be easily extended in future! In JS you can try the following Regex:

```
var re = /^(\w+(-\w+)? ?)((.* )(?!$))?(\w+(-\w+)?)$/;
var strLong = "Abc_Def-John with a Really really_LongName";
var newstrLong = strLong.replace(re, "$1$5");
console.log(newstrLong);

var strShort = "simplyJohn";
var newstrShort = strShort.replace(re, "$1$5");
console.log(newstrShort);
```